# javascript && doesn't work in wordpress post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Javascript && doesn't work in Wordpress posts. I know it is better not to write Javascript in posts, but makes sense in this case. I think there are plugins that could make this work, but got to be a simpler way... I could avoid using AND in my code logic, but that would be a pain.

I've heard that \u0026 could do it, but can't get that to work for me. I've also heard that  would work, but that doesn't work for me either. So I've done my research, but none of the solutions I've come across work.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: also would help to see the code so we know what you're up to. Why would you need to put js in a post - I assume you mean in the post body.

Comment: I'm making a calculator to do some stats on human height. People enter their height, get some stats. I know I could put the js elsewhere, but for me it makes sense to put it in the post. It's a lot of code, and not really necessary to show it all here. The basic problem is that I need conditional logic- AND: &&  as well as OR: ||

Answer (score 0):

Javascript support in every page.If you want to apply javascript in single.php file.

you can put end of file using <script> // code </script>
But make sure your php tag is complete or not before start script tag.